# Selecting entire item from repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater with a set of items that I can select by clicking on a button bound to each item. This all works great, but I was wondering is it possible to select the item in question by clicking anywhere on the row?

I imagine if it is possible, it would involve binding an event to a row upon the repeater's ItemDataBound event.

Is it possible to add an attribute to call a code behind method for row click? If so, am I going to have to use javascript?

Or is there an entirely better way of going about this?

Anyway, here is my current repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repLists" runat="server" onitemdatabound="repLists_ItemDataBound">
    <HeaderTemplate>  
        <div class="repeaterScroller" style="width: 50%">                                                                                                                                                            
            <table style="font-size:12px;" width="100%" cellpadding="5px" border="1px">                                        
                <tr class="header">
                    <td style="background-color:#f5f5f5; visibility:hidden;">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        List
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Rows
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Columns
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Pages
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Staydown
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Link
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Min
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Max
                    </td>                                 
                </tr>                                                                                                                         
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>                                              
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: center; visibility:hidden;">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButtonEdit" runat="server" OnCommand="lnkButtonEdit_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RowNumber")%>' CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>   
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["ListNo"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Description"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Rows"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Cols"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["NPages"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Staydown"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Link"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["SelMin"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["SelMax"]%>
                    </td>                                   
                </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                <tr bgcolor="#e8e8e8">
                    <td style="text-align: center; visibility:hidden;">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButtonEdit" runat="server" OnCommand="lnkButtonEdit_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RowNumber")%>' CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["ListNo"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Description"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Rows"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Cols"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["NPages"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Staydown"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["Link"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["SelMin"]%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%#((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["SelMax"]%>
                    </td>                                   
                </tr>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            </table>
        </div>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And the current click event that I want to fire by clicking on the item:

```
    protected void lnkButtonEdit_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Edit":
                break;
        }
    }
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1580368.aspx?Firing+postback+from+Repeater+row+click+ is a related problem, and I'm trying out the method there, but any advice, or other ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try it with javascript/jquery..you could simply trigger the button click event on  click..something like

```
$('.repeaterScroller tr').click(function(){
  $(this).find('input[type="button"]').click();
});
```

simply take every row, find the button in it and on row click trigger the button event. something like that

Comment: That is a really good idea, I was sure I was overcomplicating things. Thank you :) The link I posted with my question seems to work as well, adding a javascript onclick event to fire the LinkButton event for each row.